# Spring Data Rest: custom Converter<Entity, Resource> is never invoked

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest, spring-hateoas

I'm trying to implement a custom `Converter` for an `Entity` to a `Resource` object with Spring Data Rest, but the Converter is never invoked.

I'm following [this documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_the_representation):

> If your project needs to have output in a different format, however,
>   it’s possible to completely replace the default outgoing JSON
>   representation with your own. If you register your own
>   ConversionService in the ApplicationContext and register your own
>   Converter, then you can return a Resource
>   implementation of your choosing.

That's what I've tried to do.

I have a `@Configuration` class that extends `RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration`, with this method:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@EnableHypermediaSupport(type = HypermediaType.HAL)
public class RepositoryBaseConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Override
    public DefaultFormattingConversionService defaultConversionService() {
        return super.defaultConversionService();
    }

}
```

And I have a Class that extends `RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter`, with this implementation:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryBaseConfigurerAdapter extends RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureConversionService(ConfigurableConversionService conversionService) {
        if(!conversionService.canConvert(Entity.class, Resource.class))
            conversionService.addConverter(new EntityConverter());
        super.configureConversionService(conversionService);
    }

}
```

Both methods of those two classes are correctly invoked and managed, so it's natural to think that the Converter has been registered in the Application Context...

This is my custom converter EntityConverter:

```
@Component
public class EntityConverter implements Converter<Entity, Resource> {

    @Override
    public Resource convert(Entity source) {
        System.out.println("method convert of class EntityConverter");
        return null;
    }

}
```

The method "convert" is never invoked by Spring Data Rest.

What's wrong/missing ?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It says _"register your **OWN** ConversionService"_.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38611443/spring-data-rest-how-to-register-a-custom-conversionservice-with-custom-convert