# Spring Data Rest: how to register a custom conversionService with custom Converter<Entity, Resource>?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-rest

There is something that is not enough clear in [this part](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/rest/docs/current/reference/html/#_customizing_the_representation) of Spring Data Rest documentation:

> The Spring Data REST exporter executes any discovered
>   ResourceProcessor`s before it creates the output representation.

For what I have noticed, it's true: ResourceProcessor are invoked during the handling of the request, after the completion of RepositoryEntityController respective method.

> It does this by registering a `Converter<Entity, Resource>` instance
>   with an internal ConversionService.

I don't understand when it is used this `Converter<Entity,Resource>`.

> This is the component responsible for creating the links to referenced
>   entities (e.g. those objects under the _links property in the object’s
>   JSON representation). It takes an @Entity and iterates over its
>   properties, creating links for those properties that are managed by a
>   Repository and copying across any embedded or simple properties.

Sure? I noticed that the **_links** to referenced entities are created in the `RepositoryEntityController`. I didn't see any other component that builds those links: no ConversionService or Converter are involved.

> If your project needs to have output in a different format, however,
>   it’s possible to completely replace the default outgoing JSON
>   representation with your own.  If you register your own
>   ConversionService in the ApplicationContext and register your own
>   Converter, then you can return a Resource
>   implementation of your choosing.

I don't undestand how is possible to do that.

I have tried to do exactly what is written in the documentation: I have registered my own ConversionService in the ApplicationContext and my own Converter.

I have registered the ConversionService in a custom class that extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration:

```
@Configuration
public class RepositoryConfiguration extends RepositoryRestMvcConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    AuthorConverter authorConverter;

    @Bean(name="conversionService")
    public ConversionService getConversionService() {       
        DefaultFormattingConversionService conversionService = new DefaultFormattingConversionService();
        conversionService.addConverter(authorConverter);
        return conversionService;
    }

    @Override
    public DefaultFormattingConversionService defaultConversionService() {
        return (DefaultFormattingConversionService) getConversionService();
    }
}
```

This is the AuthorConverter:

```
@Component
public class AuthorConverter implements Converter<Author, Resource> {

    @Override
    public Resource convert(Author source) {
        System.out.println("convert method of class AuthorConverter");
        // still to be implemented
        return null;
    }

}
```

But the converter is never used: if I go the the `/authors` url, the JSON is solved as the standard representation, and the "convert" method of the converter is never invoked.

I want to understand (possibly with a working example) how have a custom converter that's being involved in the process of the output representation.

Thanks.

Comment: I wonder was there a solution? I encounter exactly the same problem.

Comment: Did you ever get this to work? Thinking of doing the same for my project.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38591987/spring-data-rest-custom-converterentity-resource-is-never-invoked

Comment: The linked "duplicate" also doesn't have a solution :-(     I am struggling with the same task. No luck yet.

Answer (score 1):

Does this article help? 
Source: http://www.baeldung.com/spring-httpmessageconverter-rest

"We can customize the message converters by extending the WebMvcConfigurerAdapter class and overriding the configureMessageConverters method:

```
@EnableWebMvc
@Configuration
@ComponentScan({ "org.baeldung.web" })
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void configureMessageConverters(
      List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> converters) {

        messageConverters.add(createXmlHttpMessageConverter());
        messageConverters.add(new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter());

        super.configureMessageConverters(converters);
    }
    private HttpMessageConverter<Object> createXmlHttpMessageConverter() {
        MarshallingHttpMessageConverter xmlConverter = 
          new MarshallingHttpMessageConverter();

        XStreamMarshaller xstreamMarshaller = new XStreamMarshaller();
        xmlConverter.setMarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);
        xmlConverter.setUnmarshaller(xstreamMarshaller);

        return xmlConverter;
    }
}
```